# Normal distribution of life of a semiconductor laser at a constant power

Tags: probability, statistics

> The life of a semiconductor laser at a constant power is
> normally distributed with a mean of $7000$ hours and a standard
> deviation of $600$ hours.

> (d) - A product contains three lasers, and the product fails if
> any of the lasers fails. Assume that the lasers fail independently. What should the mean life equal for $99\%$ of the
> products to exceed $10,000$ hours before failure?

Taken from $\textit{'Applied Statistics and Probability for Engineers'}$;$\;$  $6th$ edition;$\;$$2014$;$\;$p.$152/153$

Let $Y$ be the random variable for the life of the product and $X$ the random variable for life of a laser.
We're looking for the mean ${\mu'}$ such that $P(Y>10000)\geq 0.99$; but we also have that
$P(Y>10000)=P(X>10000)^3$; and:

$$\begin{align*}&
P(X>10000) = \sqrt[3]{0.99} \approx 0.9967 \\[7pt] \implies& P(\frac{X-\mu}{600}>\frac{10000-\mu}{600}) =0.9967 \\[7pt] \implies& \Phi(\frac{\mu-10000}{600})=0.9967 \\[7pt] \implies& \frac{\mu-10000}{600}=2.72 \implies \mu=11632
\end{align*}$$

But now, how can I calculate the mean life $\mu'$ of the product or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Your $\mu=11632$ looks reasonable if $\sigma=600$ as I would get about $11627.2$ taking more decimal places for $\sqrt[3]{0.99}$.  I suspect this is what the question is asking for.  If you really wanted the implied expected life for the minimum of three iid normal random variables, it gets harder.